# Step function exceeding the maximum number of characters service limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

My state in a step function flow returns an error of `state/task returned a result with a size exceeding the maximum number of characters service limit.`. In the [step function documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits.html#service-limits-task-executions), the limit for characters for input/output is `32,768 characters`. Upon checking the total characters of my result data if falls below the limit. Are there any other scenarios that it will throw that error? Thanks!

Comment: The way I went about doing this is saving things to s3, then passing the path to the file around, rather than passing the data. I understand this isn't the question, but it may help to do that instead.

Comment: @Slabgorb thanks, I used s3 for my input and result path.

Comment: Maximum payload size was just increased to 256KB: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/aws-step-functions-increases-payload-size-to-256kb/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**2020-09-29 Edit**: Step Functions now supports 256KB payloads!

256KB is the maximum size of the payload that can be passed between states. You could also exceed this limit from a Map or Parallel state, whose final output is an array with the output of each iteration or branch.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/aws-step-functions-increases-payload-size-to-256kb

The recommended solution from the Step Functions documentation is to store the data somewhere else (e.g. S3) and pass around the ARN instead of raw JSON.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/avoid-exec-failures.html

You can also use `OutputPath` to reduce the  output to the fields you want to pass to the next state.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-outputpath.html

Answer (score -2):

Based on the latest Quotas - step functions now supports 1 MB per request, it includes request header and all other associated request data.

Ref- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits-overview.html

Comment: 1 MB is request data not the "Maximum input or output size for a task, state, or execution" that is still 256 KB