# AWS Step Functions Distributed Map output exceeds maximum number of bytes service limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have `Map` in distributed mode step in a state machine, which iterates over large number of entries in S3 (>300,000 items).

Steps in the map all succeed, but the Map step itself then fails with `The state/task 'process-s3-file' returned a result with a size exceeding the maximum number of bytes service limit.` error.

I've followed advice in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55702571/step-function-exceeding-the-maximum-number-of-characters-service-limit) and set `OutputPath` to `null`, which means that every single step returns empty object now `{}`, but that didn't help for some reason. I've also set `ResultPath` of the Map step to `Discard result and keep original input`, but that also didn't help. I can confirm that each individual interation inside map is returning empty object (`{}`) now.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by enabling S3 export of results. Apparently, that overwrites the output entirely and no longer triggers output size error.